# Can the ACTION parameter in MVC Routing be renamed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have the following route in my RouteConfig,cs file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SectionHomePage",
    url: "{SectionType}/{SectionID}",
    constraints: new { SectionType = @"(Books|Cinema|Collections|Games)" },
    defaults: new { controller = "SectionHomePageController" }
    );
```

What I would like to do, if possible, is either rename the `action` parameter to `SectionType` or somehow assign `SectionType` to the `action` parameter. (I know I can just rename `SectionType` to `action` but I would like to keep the naming as it is for readability's sake).

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FFInfo.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class SectionHomePageController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /SectionHomePage/
        public ActionResult Games()
        {
            //ViewBag.Head = RouteData.Values["id"];
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> The RouteData must contain an item named 'action' with a non-empty
>   string value.

Comment: I'm not following, what's the issue exactly? Wat is your current result and what is your desired result?

Comment: The desired results is that if someone went to mysite.com/Games/GameID they would be served up the Games action of the SectionHomePageController with the GameID as a parameter passed to it. The current result is a 404 file not found (presumably because no action parameter is defined)

Comment: Please update your code and include your controller and the actionlinks from your view so we can look at the entire process of routing.

Comment: Added the controller and view code, not sure what you mean by actionlinks, if your talking about the page that generates the URL there is none, I am simply typing it into the address box of my browser.

Comment: Can you also copy the exact error message? One thing you can try: remove `SectionHomePageController` in your routing and change it to `SectionHomePage`. ASP.NET automatically adds the 'controller' and it might not have picked up it was already there.

Comment: Added error, removing the "Controller" part of the name swapped it from a 404 file not found to a server error crash.

Comment: You'll have to look into that crash since you should never add 'controller' to your routing data and thus it will always return a 404 error (it would look for a controller that doesn't exist). Specify more details about the crash you received!

Comment: I added the crash error, it is very self explanatory. It is looking for an  ACTION value but since no action is defined it crashses. either rename the action parameter to SectionType or somehow assign SectionType to the action parameter

Comment: Aah I see what you meant now. To be honest I wouldn't bother with it: you have provided a name for your route that describes its purpose and you have added limitations that describes its options. By using action you make clear that every type is an action in the standard controller, information you'd leave behind by adding redundant info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible to rename the ACTION element.

Answer (score 0):

Action is required, however you can set the action in the route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SectionHomePage",
    url: "{SectionType}/{SectionID}",
    constraints: new { SectionType = @"(Books|Cinema|Collections|Games)" },
    defaults: new { controller = "SectionHomePageController", action="Section" }
);
```

this assumes you have a SectionHomePageController with action similar to this

```
public ActionResult Section(string sectionType, int sectionId) 
{
    // can use a switch...case instead
    if (sectionType == "Books")
       return Books(sectionId);
}
public ActionResult Books(int sectionId)
{
    var model = GetBooksModel(); // load stuff
    return View("Books", model); // Set view and provide model
}
```

Alternatively you can

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SectionHomePage",
    url: "{action}/{SectionID}",
    constraints: new { action = @"(Books|Cinema|Collections|Games)" },
    defaults: new { controller = "SectionHomePageController" }
);
```

with actionResults of

```
public ActionResult Books(int sectionId) 
{
    var model = GetBooksModel(); // load stuff
    return View("Books", model); // Set view and provide model
}

public ActionResult Cinema(int sectionId) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please re-read my question. I have stated I know I can rename SectionType to action but I want to try to not do that. And adding a default action of Section does not fix anything, each SectionType will need it's own view so just running a default of Section provides no solution.

Comment: I updated my answer to have a view per section, I provided these examples because as far as I know action is required for the routes and you must either specify it in url or in the defaults